# How to properly deploy node apps to GAE with secret keys?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, secret-key, nconf

I am exploring GAE with nconf and I'm wondering if the following setup is secured after I deploy an App.

What concerns me is are both my "config.dev.json" and "config.prod.json" files deployed despite including them in ".gitignore".

I am unsure what information is passed along to gae (I don't want my config keys exposed) after I do:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Commiting'
$ glcoud app deploy
```

My Node App structure looks like this:

```
 - /myProject
   - /node_modules
   - .gitignore
   - app.js
   - app.yaml
   - config.js
   - keys.dev.json
   - keys.prod.json
   - package-lock.json
   - package.json
```

// .gitignore

```
 node_modules
 keys.dev.json
 keys.prod.json
```

// config.js:

```
 const nconf = require("nconf");
 nconf.argv().env();

 if (nconf.get("NODE_ENV") === "production") {
     nconf.file("keys.prod.json");
 } else {
     nconf.file("keys.dev.json");
 }
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Including files in `.gitignore` has no implications whatsoever on deployment on GAE, that file is only used by `git`.

If you want to prevent deployment of a file to GAE you need to use the `skip_files` option in your `app.yaml` file's [General settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#general):

> **skip_files**
>
> Optional. The **skip_files** element specifies which files in the
>   application directory are not to be uploaded to App Engine. The value
>   is either a regular expression, or a list of regular expressions. Any
>   filename that matches any of the regular expressions is omitted from
>   the list of files to upload when the application is uploaded.
>
> For example, to skip files whose names end in **.bak**, add a
>   **skip_files** section like the following:
>
> ```
> skip_files:
> - ^(.*/)?\.bak$
> ```

*Side notes*:

- if I understand correctly, your app uses those files, so it appears to me like you will *have to* deploy them together with your app.
- even if a file is deployed on GAE it is your app's responsability (and complete control) in deciding if the file is exposed to ouside requests or not.
- if you want to know exactly which files are included in the deployment you can see them displayed during deployment by using the `--verbosity` option for the [`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) command.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot.

I was following the guide on https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-mongodb-on-appengine.

I wasn't exactly sure whether there was any magic going on or whether the keys are deployed despite being in .gitignore