# Deploy Symfony project to App Engine - ERROR: Too many files

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine

First time deploying a Symfony project to Google App Engine, ran `gcloud app deploy`.

Error:

```
File upload done.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000
      files for this app.
    field: version.deployment.files[...]
```

I suspect the problem is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
# tell appengine where our static assets live
- url: /public
  static_dir: public
```

(I think I'm at least missing something to tell it not to upload the vendor stuff eg. ignore).

**How should I update my app.ymal file for project to deploy?**

PS Project folders shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the deployment verbosity using the `--verbosity` option for the [gcloud app deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) command and you'll get the list of all the files uploaded. Then use the [`skip_files`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#skip_files) option in your `app.yaml` to specify the ones you want ignored:

> Optional. The **skip_files** element specifies which files in the
>   application directory are not to be uploaded to App Engine. The value
>   is either a regular expression, or a list of regular expressions. Any
>   filename that matches any of the regular expressions is omitted from
>   the list of files to upload when the application is uploaded.
>   Filenames are relative to the project directory.
>
> The **skip_files** has the following default:
>
> ```
> skip_files:
> - ^(.*/)?#.*#$
> - ^(.*/)?.*~$
> - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
> - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
> - ^(.*/)?\..*$
> ```

Note: watch out for overwriting the defaults for this config.

I may be wrong, but your project structure image suggests your app code resides in the `src` directory. If so I'd suggest moving the `app.yaml` file inside it - the directory containing the `app.yaml` file being deployed is considered to be the top dir of the app/service - its entire content will be uploaded to GAE. You may need to adjust some paths after such move - GAE considers all app/service paths relative to this app/service top dir. If you need them, you can selectively symlink some files/directories from the project directory into the `src` dir, deployment follows symlinks, replacing them with their actual content.

Some related posts:

- [How to properly deploy node apps to GAE with secret keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238273/how-to-properly-deploy-node-apps-to-gae-with-secret-keys/48240817#48240817)
- [gcloud app deploy : This deployment has too many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451607/gcloud-app-deploy-this-deployment-has-too-many-files/42451932#42451932)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your *app.yaml*,  it looks good to me.

I think you are most likely hitting the deployment quota [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Deployments):

> The number of times the application has been uploaded by a developer. The current quota is 10,000 per day.
>   An application is limited to 10,000 uploaded files per version. Each file is limited to a maximum size of 32 megabytes.

I would try to use different services [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine) instead of having only one *huge* service. Another idea could be save some files in Google Cloud Storage [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) and access them by using Client libraries [[4]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before. I realized that my python virtual environment was under my main directory as /env so I added this to my app.yaml.

```
skip_files:
 - env/
```