# deploy nodejs app to gae/se: gcloud app deploy : This deployment has too many files

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci

I want to run gitlab-ci pipeline to deploy my express.js web app to GAE/SE environment.

When my gitlab-ci pipeline begins and runs `gcloud app deploy`, gcloud command fails as below:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000
      files for this app.
    field: version.deployment.files[...]
```

I tried to count my files using command `find . -type f | wc -l`, but it says there are only 3886 files in my repository.

My questions:

- Why GAE/SE server says there're too many files to upload?
- If I overlook something, is there any means to resolve this? (Or, I have to use flex env?)

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: node:8

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:production:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: production
    url: `${GAE_URL}`
  before_script:
    - wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
    - tar zxvf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=false --path-update=true
    - PATH="google-cloud-sdk/bin:${PATH}"
  script:
    - echo $GAE_KEY_FILE > gae_auth.json
    - ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gae_auth.json
    - ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud app deploy --project=$GAE_PROJECT_ID
  only:
  - dev
```

**.gcloudignore**

```
.git/
node_modules/
*~
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits) of 1000 files per directory and 10000 files per app on App Engine. I believe that a library being deployed with your app is causing this error. You can use the app.yaml file [**`skip_files`**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files) directive to ignore file(s)/folder(s) that are not needed from being deployed to App Engine.

To identify which file(s) are being deployed and potentially causing this error you can set the [**`verbosity`**](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity) flag to **`debug`** in your deploy command as follows.

> **gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug**

I have also found a similar StackOverflow answer that describes all of this detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51946239/10553701).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
Though ```skip_files``` settings inside app.yaml file does not resolve this issue,  ```gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug``` options help me understand its behavior more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

If I read your `.gitlab-ci.yml` correctly you seem to be installing the cloud SDK inside the same directory from which you're deploying your app - which is thus your app directory.

Since the SDK dir is not included in your `.gcloudignore` file it is uploaded as part of your application. And I counted the files in the SDK dir after your `wget` and `tar zxvf` commands:

```
$> wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
$> tar zxvf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
$> find google-cloud-sdk/ | wc -l
6442
```

Adding that to your app's 3.8k files - it's over the 10k limit.

You could try to install the SDK somewhere outside you app dir or you could add its dir pattern to the `.gcloudignore` file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your assumption is absolutely correct. After I added `google-cloud-sdk/` dir to `.gcloudignore` file, `gcloud app deploy` commands successfully finished. I think I have to know more about how docker and gitlab-ci runner works.